Paint bubbles forming over filled sections
There were numerous marks left by a Dado rail and among other things but I've used the following process:

Sand area lightly
Apply Polyfilla
Sand excess Polyfilla off
Clean wall with brush to ensure now dust remains
Apply base coat using brilliant white water based solution
Apply main paint using vinyl satin based solution

But after this process for every wall any wall where the Polyfilla was used bubbles to a huge degree where this does not happen on other walls.
I've tried sanding the bubbles lightly and repainting the area up to 4 coats of the vinyl based solution but more bubbles seem to arise the more coats are on the wall.
Was wondering if there could be any solution to this going forward, or how I can remove and redo this again if so?
There are also marks left from the Polyfilla/white water based solution

Example of bubbling appearing on specific areas:


There probably should have been steps 4A and 4B in your process:
4A: Ensure that enough drying time has been allowed for the Polyfilla to completely dry and stop off-gassing.
4B: Prime the Polyfilla areas with primer compatible with the Polyfilla and the paint.
Things that dry need time to exude gasses, and primer is almost always needed under paint.

I would usually leave 3-20hours for the Polyfilla to dry before applying coats depending on how much needed to be filled. I would have assumed that'd have been enough since it was rock hard within 2hours and left other hours to be safe.
As for the base coat there's multiple other sections where I didn't use Pollyfilla on the Dado rail line and just sanded + applied the water based base coat and there was no bubbling.

Could be a chemical reaction between the paint and Polyfilla.

I've been using a brush to remove dust after sanding on this as well, but seeing some people saying using a semi-damp microfiber cloth on the walls after filling and sanding, could it be the brush wasn't good enough for dust removal?

This would be my guess. It looks very much like the bubbling one sometimes sees when latex paint is applied directly over an incompatible surface such as oil based paint. A good primer solves that by adhering well to both.

I've used the brilliant white water based paint as a primer after applying and sanding the polyfilla though. I've applied the same primer coat except without using any polyfilla throughout multiple other walls and didn't have any bubbling, I'm thinking it's something to do with either the polyfilla not reacting well with the primer and latex paint or using a hand brush to remove dust wasn't adequate enough.

Brilliant white water based paint isn't primer, unless it says it's primer on the can.

I must have gotten some bad advise on this job then, I was advised that the Brilliant white water based paint will essential act as a primer, but if this is not the case then it could be a large cause for this issue.

I've come up with a solution. I think it may have been a result of not clearing enough of the dust after sanding the polyfill (used a dustpan brush on the wall to clear it but seems it wasn't enough). So I'm stripping back to the paint to polyfill, using a mildly damp cloth to remove the dust, then applying the primer and then painting over it with the main coat. Now it's resulting in no bubbling.
